# How to avoid inner class' name collision?

Tags: java, inner-classes

If I have a class `A` and a class `B` which is `A`'s inner class.
Also I have another class `B`. It's not in `A`.

```java
class A {
    ...
    class B {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

class B {
    ...
}
```

How do I make an instance of outer `B` in `A`?

```java
class A {
    B name = new B();
}
```

will get an instance of inner `B`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java inner class with the same name as other top level class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897853/java-inner-class-with-the-same-name-as-other-top-level-class)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify the fully-qualified name of the external `B`. If `B` is in package `com.acme`, then say `com.acme.B name = new com.acme.B();`.

Comment: A good reason to never, ever use the default package!  There are some cases where if you use the default package ("") there is simply no way to disambiguate.  I'd guess this would be such a case.