# How to access enum if inner enum having same name exist

Tags: java, enums

Unable to access values from enum defined outside class Test.

How to access enumeration constant like Reddel,Jonathan,Goldendel etc

```
enum Apple{
    Reddel,Jonathan,Goldendel,Winesap,Cortland;
}


public class Test{
    enum Apple{
        Seb,Majj,Dlred,Wipe,Cland;
    }
    public static void main(String s[]){
        //here I want to access enumeration constant from Apple outside Test.
        //Apple.Winesap
        //Apple.Goldendel
        System.out.println(Apple.Winesap);

    }
}
```

Comment: use the entire path.

Comment: what should append before `Apple.Winesap`,since this is in same package.

Comment: <packageName>.Apple vs <packageName>.Test.Apple

Comment: @EJP situatione arise like that, since i have to use method like `comapereTo` which is only applicable if both of same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your classes in a package, say

```
package pkg;
```

then using `pkg.Apple.Winesap` will work. (The fully qualified name of the other `Apple` is `pkg.Test.Apple`.)

You can also statically import the members from `pkg.Apple`:

```
import static pkg.Apple.*;
```

and then use `Winesap`.

If you're using the default package (no package declaration) then the inner `Apple` shadows the other `Apple` and you're out of luck. (Same goes for static imports; You can't statically import a member from a class in the default package.)

**Related questions:**

- [Java Inner class shadowing external class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270183/java-inner-class-shadowing-external-class)
- [Java inner class with the same name as other top level class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897853/java-inner-class-with-the-same-name-as-other-top-level-class)

Comment: these are in default package,nothing to append

Comment: Then you're out of luck I'm afraid, as stated in my last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The package name should be appended.

Comment: In this case the outer `Apple` lives in the default package, i.e. no package declaration.

Comment: Using the default package is a bad style which leads to such problems. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full package path. The below code I tested is compiling:

```
package com.my.test;

enum Apple{
    Reddel,Jonathan,Goldendel,Winesap,Cortland;
}

public class Test{
    enum Apple{
        Seb,Majj,Dlred,Wipe,Cland;
    }
    public static void main(String s[]){
        //here I want to access enumeration constant from Apple outside Test.
        //Apple.Winesap
        //Apple.Goldendel
        System.out.println(com.my.test.Apple.Winesap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case the outer `Apple` lives in the default package, i.e. no package declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The enum is declared somewhere, imagine in `ClassName.java`. You can refer them separately with `ClassName.Apple.Reddel` and `Test.Apple.Seb`

Comment: But the outer `Apple` does not live in a `Test` class, so I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: in which class is outer `Apple` declared?

Comment: It's a top-level class, so it's not declared *in* any class.

Comment: so you can't refer to outer enum if you don't change the name